Many SimpleMessageListenerContainers lead to "Consumer failed to start"
I use spring boot amqp and the x-consistent-hash RabbitMQ plugin. I need

multiple queues bound to the same x-consistent-hash exchange

separate listener for each queue to keep partial ordering


However, I see in the logs
ERROR 4828 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer failed to start in 60000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?

The app configuration is stuck and the app is started in 730 seconds without all required consumers.
The configuration is following
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory cf = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory();
        cf.setHost("localhost");
        cf.setPort(5672);
        cf.setUsername("***");
        cf.setPassword("***");
        cf.setVirtualHost("/");
        cf.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
        return new PooledChannelConnectionFactory(cf);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate feedRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin feedRabbitAdmin(RabbitTemplate feedRabbitTemplate) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(feedRabbitTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public Exchange myExchange(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
        Map<String, Object> arguments = Map.of("hash-header", "hash-on");
        Exchange exchange = new CustomExchange("my.exchange", "x-consistent-hash", true, false, arguments);
        exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(rabbitAdmin);
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean("myQueues")
    public List<Queue> myQueues(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
        List<Queue> queues = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            String queueName = String.join(".", "my.queue", Integer.toString(i));
            Queue queue = QueueBuilder.durable(queueName)
                    .singleActiveConsumer()
                    .build();

            queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(rabbitAdmin);
            rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
            queues.add(queue);
        }
        return queues;
    }

    @Bean
    public List<Binding> myBindings(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin,
                                      @Qualifier("myQueues") List<Queue> queues,
                                      Exchange exchange) {
        List<Binding> bindings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Queue queue : queues) {
            Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue)
                    .to(exchange)
                    .with("1")
                    .noargs();

            binding.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(rabbitAdmin);
            rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
            bindings.add(binding);
        }
        return bindings;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("rabbitmq-listener-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public List<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> feedListenerContainers(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin,
                                                                       @Qualifier("myQueues") List<Queue> queues,
                                                                       @Qualifier("jsonMessageConverter") Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter,
                                                                       MyMessageHandler myMessageHandler,
                                                                       TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = rabbitAdmin.getRabbitTemplate().getConnectionFactory();
        List<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> containers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Queue queue : queues) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
            container.setAmqpAdmin(rabbitAdmin);
            container.setMessageListener(new MyMessageListenerAdapter(converter, myMessageHandler));
            container.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
            container.addQueues(queue);
            containers.add(container);
            container.start();
        }
        return containers;
    }

    @Bean("jsonMessageConverter")
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        return objectMapper;
    }

What is wrong and how can it be fixed?
I tried configuring queues, bindings, and listeners separately (one bean - one object) and removing manual declaration/starting, but it did not help. I also tried using different spring boot versions, but no affect.

PooledChannelConnectionFactory allows only 8 different channels by default. Increasing the pool fixes this issue.
